# Disable skip_name_resolve in MariaDB docker

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

The MariaDB official docker (`10.6.5-focal`) has this in its `my.cnf` file:

```
[mariadbd]
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
```

It enables the `skip-name-resolve` mode. I don't want this mode to be enabled, but couldn't find a way.

Things I've tried:

One) I have a config file on the host and mount it to `/etc/mysql/conf.d`. I add this config:

```
[mariadbd]
skip-name-resolve=OFF
```

But MariaDB still starts in `skip_name_resolve` mode.

Two) I add the following to the command line when running docker:

```
docker run ... mariadb:10.6.5-focal --skip-name-resolve=0
```

Still, MariaDB runs in `skip-name-resolve` mode.

Three) It's a read-only variable and cannot be set using SQL either:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SET GLOBAL skip_name_resolve=0;
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'skip_name_resolve' is a read only variable
```

Is there a way to disable this without building my own docker image?

Comment: Mount a different `my.cnf`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Oh, I didn't know you can mount a single file! It worked! Write it as an answer please.

Comment: Actually, you just need to remove `skip-name-resolve` from `my.cnf`, save and restart MariaDB.

Comment: @FanoFN Note that the question is about Docker image. If you do that, after the next restart of the Docker, the file gets back to its original state. I'm looking for a permanent solution.

Comment: Well, you got me there. I don't have the slightest clue about Docker but from your explanation it seems that it's possible to not include the settings when building the image. As per your solution, you admit that it's not ideal therefore I'm guessing the ideal solution is _still_ building your own Docker image?

Comment: You can pass `--no-defaults --skip-host-cache` as an argument or `--defaults-file=/etc/mysql/conf.d/something-else.cnf`.

Comment: Shouldn't you writte it like this: ```
--skip_name_resolve=OFF
```

Comment: Another option is to create a Dockerfile from the official MariaDB image and then add `RUN rm /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/05-skipcache.cnf`.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective method to handle this situation is by including a custom configuration file (cnf) alongside the existing ones. This is particularly useful for managing the skip-name-resolve option in MariaDB, which is included in its default configuration. To specifically address this, MariaDB offers a variable named disable-skip-name-resolve to control this feature. By utilizing this approach, updates to Docker images can be executed more smoothly.

Below is how you can achieve this using Docker Compose:

```yaml
  database:
    image: mariadb:10.6.12
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./docker/my-resolve.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my-resolve.cnf:ro
    # other stuff...
```

And the file `my-resolve.cnf`:

```
[mariadb]
disable-skip-name-resolve=1
```

Answer (score 0):

As Boris the Spider suggest, `my.cnf` can be mounted from the host. I copied the `my.cnf` file from the image to the host, removed the two options, then mount it at the run time.

```
docker run ... -v /HOST/PATH/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf ...
```

This is not very ideal because if the official image changes `my.cnf` file, then I need to remember to copy the file to the host again (extra maintenance cost). But that seems better than re-creating the image myself.